# Issue in showing 24-Hour Format time

Tags: java, android, datetime

I have used following line code to display time in 24-Hour format from the `Calendar` Instance
Everything show correctly, but only problem is while showing time at midnight 12:00 am, It show time as 24:00 instead of showing 00:00. Why this happen anything wrong in my code.

```
Calendar m_CalInstance = Calendar.getInstance();  
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");

String timeDisplay = formatter.format(m_CalInstance.getTime());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
```

should be

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
```

Check this [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more information on `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: Is that javadoc wrong? it says `H Hour in day (0-23)` and `k Hour in day (1-24)`, so should the correct answer be `HH:mm`?

Comment: @KenY-N: After reading question again, you are correct. OP should use HH to get 0-23. Updated answer. Thanks for pointing

Comment: Sorry, pressed the Enter button too early by accident! It does seem odd that the uppercase H and K have the reverse meanings from the lowercase h and k. Is this a legacy feature/bug?

Comment: @KenY-N: Sure that is not bug, which leaves us with legacy design.

Comment: @Nambari Ken Y-N Thanks to both of you...yeh now its show what i want

Answer (score 0):

use capital letters **KK** inplace of `kk` here

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("KK:mm");
```